# How to get .last object according to .id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have in my view `duel.duelers.last`, which is suppose to grab the `dueler` with the last id in the duel, but instead if a dueler updates an attribute then that dueler becomes last regardless of its order in `id`?

How can I grab the last dueler based on `id`?

```
pry(main)> Duel.last.duelers
=> [#<Dueler:0x007fa718513530
  id: 310, # This is Duel.last.duelers.last but is listed first here
  user_id: 2,
  challenge_id: 398,
  duel_id: 186,
 #<Dueler:0x007fa718513288
  id: 309, # This is Duel.last.duelers.first but is listed last here because it was most recently updated
  user_id: 114, 
  challenge_id: 410,
  duel_id: 186,
pry(main)> Duel.last.duelers.last
 id: 310,
 user_id: 2,
 challenge_id: 398,
 duel_id: 186,
pry(main)> Duel.last.duelers.first
 id: 309,
 user_id: 114,
 challenge_id: 410,
 duel_id: 186,
```

Comment: `Dueler ` does not have `updated_at` column? If it is, then probably creating a scope on it should help.

Comment: @Surya `scope` seems neat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to grab the last dueler based on id,

No matter what column you update last in your table, **the basic query will be ordered by `duelers_id desc`**

**Rails default order:**

In rails if there is no order specified by default, so they will be ordered by how the database returns them. `Usually this is by ID or insert order`. The `created_at/updated_at` column is only there if you specify it in your migrations so it wouldn't make sense for that to be the default order column.

Here is an example query I made for you.

```
Duel.last.duelers.last

Duel Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `duels`.* FROM `duels`  ORDER BY `duels`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1

Dueler Load (37.3ms)  SELECT `duelers`.* FROM `duelers` WHERE `duelers`.`duel_id` = 1 ORDER BY `duelers`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

This query first loads the respective Duel and then gets the last dueler of that duel **order by dueler_id desc.**

Check the query,

**`SELECT`duelers`.* FROM`duelers`WHERE`duelers`.`duel_id`= 1 ORDER BY`duelers`.`id`DESC LIMIT 1`**

**it always order by id desc unless you give a default scope.**

In your question, it is getting the results in the correct order which is the descending order of Id

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com, have you checked this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Duel.last.duelers.order(id: :desc).first
```

Or

```
Duel.last.duelers.order(created_at: :desc).first
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: order by `id` seems better than `created_at`

Comment: @Deepak: Why? The only thing that's really guaranteed about `id` is that they're unique. You're usually better off being explicit about the ordering you want so timestamps are better.